# Are there any flags i need to provide to CefSharp to work with document elements?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I converted a window of mine to use CefSharp in order to render some PDF file. One of the features the old component supported (WebBrowser of WPF, which unfortunately depends on IE, which does not work in this case) is accessing javascript elements through code in order to be aware of when the PDF has been scrolled to the bottom. Unfortunately this does not appear to work with CefSharp with the following code. Perhaps i am missing some initializer flag for this to work?

Currently in my Logs All i get is ScrollProgress|0|0|734

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using CefSharp;
using NLog;
using Application = System.Windows.Application;
using MessageBox = System.Windows.MessageBox;
using WebBrowser = System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class PdfConfirmWindow : Window
    {
        private static readonly ILogger Log = LogManager.GetLogger(nameof(PdfConfirmWindow));

        public PdfConfirmWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ChromiumWebBrowser.LoadingStateChanged += ChromiumWebBrowserOnLoadingStateChanged;
            UpdateBrowserContent();
        }

        private void ChromiumWebBrowserOnLoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.IsLoading)
            {
                Log.Debug("Loading completed");
                
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    // (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight
                    // e.scrollHeight - e.scrollTop === e.clientHeight
                    // CefSharp.PostMessage('EndOfDocumentReached');

                    const string script = @"

(function(){
    var intervalHandler;
    function onScrollCallback() {
        var e = document.body;
        var values = ['ScrollProgress'];
        values.push(document.body.clientHeight);
        values.push(window.scrollY);
        values.push(window.innerHeight);

        CefSharp.PostMessage(values.join('|'));

        if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight){
            //clearInterval(intervalHandler);
        }
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        var intervalHandler = setInterval(function(){
            onScrollCallback();
        }, 100);
    }, 500);

})();

";
                    ChromiumWebBrowser.Focus();
                    ChromiumWebBrowser.WebBrowser.JavascriptMessageReceived += WebBrowserOnJavascriptMessageReceived;
                    ChromiumWebBrowser.WebBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
                }));
            }
        }

        private async void WebBrowserOnJavascriptMessageReceived(object sender, JavascriptMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            await UIHelper.Thread;

            // ChromiumWebBrowser.WebBrowser.JavascriptMessageReceived -= WebBrowserOnJavascriptMessageReceived;
            if (e.Message?.ToString().Equals("EndOfDocumentReached", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                SetReachedStatus(true);
            }
            if (e.Message?.ToString().StartsWith("ScrollProgress", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                Log.Debug(e.Message?.ToString());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: No magic settings, I actually doubt what you are trying to achieve is possible. Pdfium which renders the PDF files is independent of the DOM. You can try asking on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php to see if someone has a creative workaround.

Comment: @amaitland Using wpf's built in WebBrowser this can be done. But that one is not an option sadly. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Thinking about it you could use pdfjs to render the pdf in JavaScript,  you'd then have complete control.  https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/